# C# Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position 0

Tags: c#, json, stream, streamreader, jsonreader

I'm trying to parse my json with the code below. I get the error:

> Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position 0.

I thought this might be because my JSON was malformed, so I have output it, and it appears to be ok:

```
{ 
    "serviceDeskId": "4", 
    "requestTypeId": "223", 
    "requestFieldValues": { 
        "summary": "test" 
    } 
}
```

But now I'm completely stuck. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? This is driving me crazy!!

It's on this line that the error is triggered:

```
var jsonresponse = JObject.Parse(response);
```

Complete code snippet:

```
req.ContentType = "application/json";

                var json = JObject.Parse(
                        "{\"serviceDeskId\": \"4\",\"requestTypeId\": \"223\",\"requestFieldValues\": {\"summary\": \"" +
                        summary.Value + "\"}}");

                jsonCheck = json.ToString();

                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
                    {

                        streamWriter.Write(json);
                    }

                    HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;


                    // Obtain a 'Stream' object associated with the response object.
                    Stream ReceiveStream = resp.GetResponseStream();

                    Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");

                    String response = "";

                    // Pipe the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format. 
                    StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(ReceiveStream, encode);

                    response = readStream.ReadToEnd();

                    // Release the resources of stream object.
                    readStream.Close();

                    // Release the resources of response object.
                    resp.Close();

                    var jsonresponse = JObject.Parse(response);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try to output response to text file (or if in visual studio - add breakpoint and check value) before trying to parse it - jsonreader does not recognise response as valid json. If there's an error - you'll see it.

Comment: What's the server doing with your JSON data? Will it simply echo? IMO the problem is related to encoding (BOM) - maybe the server sends unicode and you're reading utf8? Have a look at the response on the byte level.

Answer (score 1):

I've only seen this error when the input is exactly empty string. Check that your text is making it to that varible.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var json = JObject.Parse("");
        Console.WriteLine(json);
        
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/u0FMLS

Answer (score 0):

Ah I believe I had this issue before. What I found out is that Visual Studio saves the json files in a different way. You can check this in the following way:

1. In Visual Studio go to File -> Open and **point** to your json file
2. Then click the small arrow near the "Open" button and choose "Open With.."
3. When the "Open With" dialog opens choose "Binary Editor" and click OK

[NOTE: The previous steps could have been accomplished with using some other Hex editor.]

After the file is opened, in its HEX format, see if it starts with `...{..`
 or ends with `..}..` and remove the starting dots ".." and the ending dots ".."  and save the file and try again.

This happens if you create a json file inside Visual Studio.

Alternatively you can create a new file with some other program (like Notepad ++) and use that file.

Hope this helps.